# Writing XML to file using LXML

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, lxml

I'm trying to create a XML file using LXML. So far I have ...

```
from lxml import etree

def exportAsXML(self, filename):
    fields = [
        ('Realm', self.Realm),
        ('ActiveState', self.ActiveState),
        ('Name', self.Name),
        ('Type', self.Type),
        ('Level', self.Level),
        ('Quality', self.Quality),
        ('Bonus', self.Bonus),
        ('AFDPS', self.AFDPS),
        ('Speed', self.Speed),
        ('Origin', self.Origin),
        ('DamageType', self.DamageType),
        ('LeftHand', self.LeftHand),
        ('Requirement', self.Requirement),
        ('Notes', self.Notes,)
    ]

    root = etree.Element('Item')
    for key, value in fields:
        if value != '':
            etree.SubElement(root, key).text = value

    document = open(filename, 'w')
    document.write(etree.tostring(root, pretty_print = True))
    document.close()
```

This results in `TypeError: must be str, not bytes` but I don't understand what is going on. I assume by using `etree.tostring` that the etree object is converted to a string, but that doesn't seem to be the case. Any idea?

** UPDATE **

What I'm trying to do is create a valid XML file that is neatly formatted using LXML and contains a DTD (not implemented yet). I already make use of LXML in other areas of my application, so I figured I would continue on with it. I'm using Python 3.

** UPDATE 2 **

> console

```
b'<Item><Realm>All</Realm><ActiveState>Dropped</ActiveState><Name>Band</Name><Type>Wrist</Type><Level>50</Level><Quality>100</Quality><Bonus>35</Bonus><Origin>Quest</Origin></Item>'
```

> file

```
<Item><Realm>All</Realm><ActiveState>Dropped</ActiveState><Name>Band</Name><Type>Wrist</Type><Level>50</Level><Quality>100</Quality><Bonus>35</Bonus><Origin>Quest</Origin></Item>
```

Comment: try `etree.SubElement(root, key.decode('utf-8')).text = str(value, 'utf-8')`

Comment: @sKwa Throws a new exception: `TypeError: decoding str is not supported`

Comment: so try to modify `str(value, 'utf-8')` to `str(value)`.

Comment: @sKwa Tried that, and no dice. Same exception as before. Not sure what I'm missing here. I have combed through the documentation, and looked at other examples, but still can't figure this out.

Comment: it fails on line - `etree.tostring(...)`?

Comment: @sKwa It fails at `document.write(etree.tostring(...))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For XML files, simply use the `'wb'` argument in `open()` and consider context manager, `with`:

```
with open(filename, 'wb') as doc:
   doc.write(etree.tostring(root, pretty_print = True))
```

---

As demonstration, below tests OP's routine with slight change to *self* variables with output in pretty print format:

```
def exportAsXML(filename):
    fields = [
        ('Realm', 'self.Realm'),
        ('ActiveState', 'self.ActiveState'),
        ('Name', 'self.Name'),
        ('Type', 'self.Type'),
        ('Level', 'self.Level'),
        ('Quality', 'self.Quality'),
        ('Bonus', 'self.Bonus'),
        ('AFDPS', 'self.AFDPS'),
        ('Speed', 'self.Speed'),
        ('Origin', 'self.Origin'),
        ('DamageType', 'self.DamageType'),
        ('LeftHand', 'self.LeftHand'),
        ('Requirement', 'self.Requirement'),
        ('Notes', 'self.Notes')
    ]

    root = etree.Element('Item')
    for key, value in fields:
        if value != '':
            etree.SubElement(root, key).text = value

    with open(filename, 'wb') as doc:
        doc.write(etree.tostring(root, pretty_print = True))

exportAsXML('Output.xml')
```

**Output**

```
<Item>
  <Realm>self.Realm</Realm>
  <ActiveState>self.ActiveState</ActiveState>
  <Name>self.Name</Name>
  <Type>self.Type</Type>
  <Level>self.Level</Level>
  <Quality>self.Quality</Quality>
  <Bonus>self.Bonus</Bonus>
  <AFDPS>self.AFDPS</AFDPS>
  <Speed>self.Speed</Speed>
  <Origin>self.Origin</Origin>
  <DamageType>self.DamageType</DamageType>
  <LeftHand>self.LeftHand</LeftHand>
  <Requirement>self.Requirement</Requirement>
  <Notes>self.Notes</Notes>
</Item>
```

Comment: That works, but it is printing everything on 1 line. I was under the assumption that `pretty_print = True` would rectify that issue.

Comment: It should if `etree` points to `lxml.etree`. Your post does not indicate the library and does not set up a reproducible example for us to verify. Try printing in console `print(etree.tostring(..., pretty_print = True))`.

Comment: Ah! Another issue is you do not have a *root* to your XML output. Please post the etree string.

Comment: Pardon my confusion, I'm new to working with xml in Python, what string are you looking for? I added `from lxml import etree` to my original post for clarification. print(...) resulted in a one line string `b'<Item>\n ... </item>`

Comment: to add to the above comment, the xml document it generated has all the necessary spacing, but doesn't seem to respect `\n` to create a new line.

Comment: That printed exactly how I expected, and I changed `open(filename, 'wb')` to `open(filename, 'w')` and added `.decode` to the `write` statement, and that seemed to fix my issue. Although with all the searching I did, this is the first I have seen the need for this.

Comment: With the changes I made, it seems to be working fine, but it feels hackish in how it turned out. I had expected that if `pretty_print` was working correctly then there was no need to decode to UTF-8.

Comment: First, always edit post with data and/or code and not in comments. Please do so and then delete this long comment. Also see my edit testing your exact process with my answer that does render pretty print output. Hence, I cannot reproduce your claimed *one-liner*.

Comment: updated, and I'm still getting the same 1 line output for everything. I'm not really sure what is going on. If I use `.decode('UTF-8')` everything outputs as expected. I will post a new question for this.

Comment: Check if elsewhere you are outputting or updating this XML. I cannot see entire class or how methods run. Try running my extended answer, does it pretty print for you? What text editor/program are you using to see this one line output?

Comment: It does not `pretty_print` for me. I created a new script and ran the code directly adding only `from lxml import etree`. I added the `.decode('UTF-8')` and it printed how I would expect.

Comment: Very interesting! Something might be at issue with your Python or lxml install. Are you using an IDE like Jupyter, Spyder, PyCharm? Try running script at command line in terminal (Bash, PowerShell): `python /path/to/script.py`.

Comment: I do use PyCharm, so I took your advice and ran it from console, but it still has the same issue. Is this perhaps a difference between Python 2 and 3?

Comment: I use Python 3 as you do. What OS are you running? And what text editor?

Comment: I'm use Windows 10 Professional, and opening the XML file via Notepad. When using the decode option, notepad displays the XML perfectly. On the other hand I just tested the XML with Notepad++ and it seems to be formatted correctly. I didn't think about how "incapable" notepad was. It just seems silly that it won't display it properly.

Comment: Yes, I can confirm on a Windows 7 machine. Glad we found the issue! Wordpad and browser would show indentation. Notepad requires `unicode` encoding to respect line breaks and tabs which you can pass in `etree.tostring(root, encoding='unicode', pretty_print = True)` and change `open()` argument from `wb` to `w` since this converts to byte to string.